# ForkJoin throwing error when source is passed as variable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have `forkjoin` implemented as follows:

```js
   getData() {
    forkJoin({
      a: of([1, 2, 3]),
      b: of([4, 5, 6]),
      c: of([7, 8, 9])
    }).subscribe(r => {
      console.log(r.a, r.b, r.c);
    });
  }
```

This code works and I can see the output on console, However if I move the source to a variable, `forkoin` is not working anymore.

```js
   getData() {
    const source = {
      a: of([1, 2, 3]),
      b: of([4, 5, 6]),
      c: of([7, 8, 9])
    };
    forkJoin(source).subscribe(r => {
      console.log(r.a, r.b, r.c);
    });
  }
```

Its throwing error:

> Property 'a' does not exist on type 'never'.

Why this is happening and how to fix it ?.

StackBlitz can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-question-forkjoin?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nyks-rxjs-skelaton-5rc4d4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer, stackblitz linked. First answer didn’t mention the solution. You cannot pass the type conversion in the angle brackets of the forkJoin, you need to just add the type in the callback. Use typeof source to not define a new type. Assigning a type to source, nor making it as const provides the correct type definition. Only giving a type in the callback seems to work.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-question-forkjoin-so?file=src/app/app.component.ts